# Don't Shrink WebView in Android lollipop

Tags: android, webview

I'm using the `contentEditable='true'` for webview in android lollipop version.
When i increase the width, the webview is shrinking but i want to scroll the content horizontally.

This works good in pre-lollipop versioned devices.

Please help me.